# How to get values from string using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string as below.

`'<NOV 20, 2017 5:20:17, 20PM IST> <Summary> <USER-1000-1 2017-11-20 08:150:80, 2000'`

Using Python I need to extract values from the above string and output should display as below

**Output:**

````
   Date: 20-NOV-2017
   USER: 1000
   Time: 08:150:80```
````

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem yourself at all?

Comment: no I am using split method after that i am doing trial and error method . But I am not getting anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, using `re.search` with five capture groups to piece together the output the way you expect:

```
inp = '<NOV 20, 2017 5:20:17, 20PM IST> <Summary> <USER-1000-1 2017-11-20 08:150:80, 2000'
match = re.search(r'^<(\w{3}) (\d+), (\d{4}).*\bUSER-(\d+).*\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (.*?),.*$', inp)
if match:
    print("Date: " + match.group(2) + "-" + match.group(1) + "-" + match.group(3))
    print("USER: " + match.group(4))
    print("Time: " + match.group(5))
```

This prints:

```
Date: 20-NOV-2017
USER: 1000
Time: 08:150:80
```

Note that splitting, even using a regex, may not be the best approach here, as there is no clear delimiter which would work everywhere.